# What should on-topic but excessively general questions be voted as?

Tags: discussion, area-51

Take these questions:

[which is better, windmill or selenium?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4693/selenium/4857#4857) (selenium)

[which is better, linux or windows?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3924/unix-linux/8058#8058) (unix and linux)

[Which is better -- Drupal, Joomla, or WordPress?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2978/drupal-answers/2992#2992) (drupal)

All of them have accrued large amounts of off-topic votes (and virtually no other votes). But aren't these ON-topic questions for the sites? They are far too broad and very subjective when asked that way, but are by no means 'off-topic'. [If an avid selenium, linux, or drupal user sees one of these questions listed as off-topic, they will probably leave the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53919/difference-between-great-off-topic-example-and-not-a-good-example)

I normally vote these as 'not a good example' because they are on-topic, but should not be asked on the site in this form. **How should I vote?**

Answer (score 5):

They should really be voted 'meh' as they're not good examples of what the boundaries should be for the proposed site.

Comment: how do we vote 'meh'?

Comment: @Crazy: meh = Not a Good Example

Answer (score 1):

You are right... They are wrong.

**Please comment with a link to [*this* post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53919/difference-between-great-off-topic-example-and-not-a-good-example/53925#53925) whenever you see this mistake in Proposals:**

[Difference between “great off topic example” and “not a good example”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53919/difference-between-great-off-topic-example-and-not-a-good-example/53925#53925)

It's not like comparisons or questions about those subjects are off-topic. They are just horribly asked. Closed as subjective. But that does *not* make them *off topic.*

Essentially:

> Don't confuse the reasons to close a question with whether a question is on- or off- topic. Those off-topic questions are supposed to tell you what the site is not about... What questions would be [closed as off-topic].
>
> The fact that a sample question is too broad or too subjective is a terrible, terrible, terrible reason to vote the question as a "great off-topic example."

Answer (score 0):

Coparison questions may not be a great example of an off-topic question, but I don't think they are meh either.

In the end, I don't think it will be that important which questions are selected. The point is not so much finding 5 perfect questions. What's really interesting is the discussion about the questions, mostly happening in the comments.

I don't think anybody will look at the 10 questions for a proposal in commit phase and say:

> That question is so good, I'll joon the site.

or

> that question is so awefull, I'll never join that site.

What's building the sites is communities after all, not perfect example questions.