# Do people "get" what off-topic means on Area 51?

Tags: discussion, area-51, off-topic

I wonder if we need to change the wording used for  "off topic" suggestions in Area 51. I think some people take this too literally.

I believe a good "off topic" question is one that *some* people would think was appropriate, but the community feels doesn't belong on the site.

To take SO for example, a great off-topic question might be "What kind of chair do you sit in while programming". In Area 51 I think many people would say this was "on topic", but a poor question. Taken too literally, "what's your favorite color" would be "off topic", when in reality it should just be rated a poor example.

In other words, I think some people are getting these two choices confused.

Has anyone else noticed this problem? What can we do to clarify it.

Comment: *getting these three choices confused

Comment: @Justin L - I don't think the "good on-topic" choice is confusing.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52622/not-a-good-example-is-misleading-maybe and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53919/difference-between-great-off-topic-example-and-not-a-good-example

Answer (score 4):

I actually had a slightly different understanding of "off-topic"; I thought it was for questions that didn't really belong but were likely to be posted in good faith.

So, no, people don't get what "off-topic" means on Area 51.  One of us has to at least be more right than the other.

Comment: That's exactly what I think. I'm saying that _some_ people visiting the proposed site would ask an "off-topic" question, thinking it was on-topic/appropriate for the site.

Comment: To put it another way, "off-topic" questions are questions that are likely to be asked and likely to be closed.

Comment: Hm, I was thinking of new users unfamiliar with the SE model.  I did misunderstand you.  Very good.